# How to replace word under caret position in richtextbox ? - implementing spellcheck suggestions

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, richtextbox, spell-checking

I have a derived version of RichTextBox with custom spell checkers. They provide me a list of suggestions for a misspelled word.
I would like to achieve the **same correction functionality as in MS Word**.

If the users right-clicks a word, how do I get a string containing just 1 word?

Once I have the list of suggestions, I would load them to the ContextMenu of the richtextbox.

After selecting a word from the context menu, how do I replace the word?

Note **I cannot operate on whole TextRange(start,end).Text**, because the RichTextBox contains objects other than text and they would disappear if I modify the Text property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to get the current position of the mouse in the RichTextBox as a TextPointer using the following (where rtb is a RichTextBox):

```
var mousePosition = Mouse.GetPosition(rtb);
var textPointer = rtb.GetPositionFromPoint(mousePosition, false);
```

Given the pointer you can use some methods like the following for getting and replacing a word at a specified position (you may want to change the rules for which characters count as words, though)

```
private string GetWordAtPointer(TextPointer textPointer)
{
    return string.Join(string.Empty, GetWordCharactersBefore(textPointer), GetWordCharactersAfter(textPointer));
}

private void ReplaceWordAtPointer(TextPointer textPointer, string replacementWord)
{
    textPointer.DeleteTextInRun(-GetWordCharactersBefore(textPointer).Count());
    textPointer.DeleteTextInRun(GetWordCharactersAfter(textPointer).Count());

    textPointer.InsertTextInRun(replacementWord);
}

private string GetWordCharactersBefore(TextPointer textPointer)
{
    var backwards = textPointer.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Backward);
    var wordCharactersBeforePointer = new string(backwards.Reverse().TakeWhile(c => !char.IsSeparator(c) && !char.IsPunctuation(c)).Reverse().ToArray());

    return wordCharactersBeforePointer;
}

private string GetWordCharactersAfter(TextPointer textPointer)
{
    var fowards = textPointer.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    var wordCharactersAfterPointer = new string(fowards.TakeWhile(c => !char.IsSeparator(c) && !char.IsPunctuation(c)).ToArray());

    return wordCharactersAfterPointer;
}
```